# Program made with create-react-app does not work offline

Tags: reactjs, offline-caching

I am working on my first little create-react-app program. I would like it to work offline, and the documentation says it should. When I run the production version offline I get a message like

`GET http://localhost:3001/static/css/main.6a923b45.css net::ERR_INTERNET_DISCONNECTED
localhost/:1 GET http://localhost:3001/static/js/main.77163466.js net::ERR_INTERNET_DISCONNECTED
An unknown error occurred when fetching the script.
service-worker.js Failed to load resource: net::ERR_INTERNET_DISCONNECTED`

I don't think that the main.js is getting cached by the service worker, but I could be wrong. Any Ideas?

Here is the package.json as requested:

```
{
      "name": "my-app",
      "version": "0.1.0",
      "private": true,
      "dependencies": {
        "localforage": "^1.5.0",
        "react": "^15.6.1",
        "react-dom": "^15.6.1",
        "react-scripts": "1.0.10",
        "react-toggle": "^4.0.1",
        "recordrtc": "^5.4.2",
        "squat": "^0.1.0",
        "sw-precache": "^4.0.0",
      },
      "scripts": {
        "start": "react-scripts start",
        "build": "react-scripts build",
        "test": "react-scripts test --env=jsdom",
        "eject": "react-scripts eject"
      },
      "homepage": "./"
}
```

Is there a max file size for sw-cache?

Comment: can you please provied your package.json?

Comment: and probably it would be a better way to think about webpack. I promise you you will need it!

Comment: I added the package.json

Comment: There is no such thing as `react-create-app`. Are you talking about **create-react-app** ?

Comment: Looking at your `package.json` shows you have installed extra packages. By default, `create-react-app` should have no problem. Your question seems to mean when you create a new app using that command, it does not work offline. I don't think that is true. Please reword your question.

Answer (score 1):

In order for a web application to work offline you have to go to the page with internet first to be cached by the browser and if you have accessed to the page with internet before make sure that in your build folder the file **service-worker.js** is present

Comment: your whole answer! you can run the application offline without been online bevore. and there has no service-worker.js to be! ... best advice is to provide the package.json and look at his scripts

Comment: 1) When you run the command npm run build with a create-react-app project, in the build folder you should have a file named service-worker.js and in the main.*.js that file is registered, if you don't have one you won't have any SW feature

Comment: 2) I said the part of the internet connection because he clearly has this error: service-worker.js Failed to load resource: net::ERR_INTERNET_DISCONNECTED so he probably killed the localhost server trying to test the offline behavior before caching the files with the SW before